# Why my store does not load data even though data is returned

Tags: extjs

I can't tell why my store does not bind the the data returned from the server. Thank you in advance.

Here is how I instantiate and call "load":

```
var store = Ext.create('Iip.store.giip.other.States');
store.load({
    params: {c: 'get_states'},
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        console.log(records); **<=== never prints**
    }
});
```

Here is the store:

```
Ext.define("Iip.store.giip.other.States", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    storeId:"states-store",
    model: "Iip.model.giip.other.State",
    autoLoad: false,
    buffered: true
});
```

Here is the model:

```
Ext.define('Iip.model.giip.other.State', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: "stateId",

    fields:[
        {name: "stateId", type: "int"},
        {name: "state", type: "string"}
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        actionMethods: {
            read: "POST"
        },
        api: {
            read: "indexes/common_index.php"
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: "states"
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation, opts) {
                if(typeof(operation.error) == "string") {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Connection to server interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the data returned from the server in firebug:

```
{"states":[{"stateId":"1","state":"AL"},{"stateId":"2","state":"AK"},
{"stateId":"3","state":"AS"},{"stateId":"4","state":"AZ"},{"stateId":"5","state":"AR"},           
{"stateId":"6","state":"CA"},{"stateId":"7","state":"CO"},{"stateId":"8","state":"CT"},
{"stateId":"9","state":"DE"},{"stateId":"10","state":"DC"},
{"stateId":"11","state":"FM"},{"stateId":"12","state":"FL"},
{"stateId":"13","state":"GA"},{"stateId":"14","state":"GU"},
{"stateId":"15","state":"HI"},{"stateId":"16","state":"ID"},
{"stateId":"17","state":"IL"},{"stateId":"18","state":"IN"},
{"stateId":"19","state":"IA"},{"stateId":"20","state":"KS"},
{"stateId":"21","state":"KY"},{"stateId":"22","state":"LA"},
{"stateId":"23","state":"ME"},{"stateId":"24","state":"MH"},
{"stateId":"25","state":"MD"},{"stateId":"26","state":"MA"},
{"stateId":"27","state":"MI"},{"stateId":"28","state":"MN"},
{"stateId":"29","state":"MS"},{"stateId":"30","state":"MO"},
{"stateId":"31","state":"MT"},{"stateId":"32","state":"NE"},
{"stateId":"33","state":"NV"},{"stateId":"34","state":"NH"},
{"stateId":"35","state":"NJ"},{"stateId":"36","state":"NM"},
{"stateId":"37","state":"NY"},{"stateId":"38","state":"NC"},
{"stateId":"39","state":"ND"},{"stateId":"40","state":"MP"},
{"stateId":"41","state":"OH"},{"stateId":"42","state":"OK"},
{"stateId":"43","state":"OR"},{"stateId":"44","state":"PW"},
{"stateId":"45","state":"PA"},{"stateId":"46","state":"PR"},
{"stateId":"47","state":"RI"},{"stateId":"48","state":"SC"},
{"stateId":"49","state":"SD"},{"stateId":"50","state":"TN"}, 
{"stateId":"51","state":"TX"},{"stateId":"52","state":"UT"},
{"stateId":"53","state":"VT"},{"stateId":"54","state":"VA"},
{"stateId":"55","state":"VI"},{"stateId":"56","state":"WA"},
{"stateId":"57","state":"WV"},{"stateId":"58","state":"WI"},
{"stateId":"59","state":"WY"}]}
```

Here is the combo the data is supposed to bind to:

```
{
                                xtype: 'combo',
                                fieldLabel: 'State',
                                store: store,
                                displayField: 'state',
                                valueField: 'stateId',
                                anchor:'97%',
                                itemId: 'fatherState',
                                editable: false,
                                allowBlank: false,
                                emptyText: 'Select a state',
                                tabIndex: 6,
                                queryMode: 'local'
                            }
```

Comment: Store loading is asynchronous, by the time you've logged the count, it hasn't returned from the server yet.

Comment: but what about logging the records in the callback? there it should print the number of records

Comment: console.log(records) never prints anything. That is what puzzles me.

Comment: You don't see your combo with the elements right? what about logging the store to see if it has any records? or logging operation in the callback to get some info... I would also put the proxy on my store and add "success":true to my json ...

Comment: try to get store of your combo..with `getStore()` method...I'm quite doubtful with combo store..

Answer (score 0):

try after change this two fiels like below

store:

```
    Ext.define("Iip.store.giip.other.States", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Store",
        config: {
           storeId:"states-store",
           model: "Iip.model.giip.other.State",
           autoLoad: false,
           buffered: true,
           proxy: {
              type: "ajax",
              actionMethods: {
                  read: "POST"
              },
             api: {
                read: "indexes/common_index.php"
              },
              reader: {
                type: "json",
                root: "states"
             },
             listeners: {
                 exception: function(proxy, response, operation, opts) {
                 if(typeof(operation.error) == "string") {
                      Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Connection to server interrupted");
                 }
             }
          }
        }
      }

    });
```

model:

```
    Ext.define('Iip.model.giip.other.State', {
          extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
          idProperty: "stateId",

          fields:[
            {name: "stateId", type: "int"},
             {name: "state", type: "string"}
          ]


   });
```

Comment: I tried our suggestion by putting the proxy into the store, but my combo still does not have the states in it.

Comment: I also tried this. I just create a store without loading and assign to the combo. After the combo is rendered, I load. However, the callback function is, again, never invoked. This is driving me nuts. I am coming to the end of things I can try.

Comment: Here is the code I tried mentioned in my previous comment: `listeners: {
  afterrender: function() {
   var state = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#fatherState')[0];
   state.getStore().load({
    params: { c: 'get_states'},
    callback: function(records, st, suc) {
     console.log(records);
     console.log(state.getStore().getTotalCount());
    }
   });
  }
 },`

Comment: I just noticed that when I click on the trouble combo, it makes a request whose url is the url I specified in the model's proxy's read action (indexes/common_index.php). And here is the what gets posted: "filter [{"property":"state"}]. 
limit 25
page 1
start 0"  This request is even more puzzling because nowhere in my code the combo is wired to any event to make a request.

Comment: Start a project in Sencha Fiddle web page... as soon as I have time I ll do it myself and be back here

Comment: It turns out it does not show options in my combo because my store wants buffer support, which is not supported in 4.x: Here is the new code for my store: `Ext.define("Iip.store.giip.other.States", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    storeId:"states-store",
    model: "Iip.model.giip.other.State",
    autoLoad: false/*,
    buffered: true*/ <====take this out
});`

Comment: It turns out that all you need to is to take out the "buffered: true" line in the store as 4.x does not support buffer. Here is the new store (without "buffered: true): `Ext.define("Iip.store.giip.other.States", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    storeId:"states-store",
    model: "Iip.model.giip.other.State",
    autoLoad: false
});`